# Eclipse crashes on importing a library

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey guys I am having issue with eclipse. Every time when I want to import some library lets say org.opencv eclipse crashes. It crashes in the moment when I write dot org(dot)opencv. Have you seen somthing like this? Can you help me to fix it please? 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04,
adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.

I also recorded a video [http://tinypic.com/r/2nm15ip/8][1].

Thank you for your help.

I tried it open in terminal and of course it crashed but i got some answer:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
NOT SANDBOXED
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc79f6052a1, pid=9886, tid=140499127801600
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_72-b14) (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.72-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/nemesis/NEW_Android_Development_Enviroment/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/hs_err_pid9886.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

And also I found out that in my eclispe folder has been created error report.

I uploaded it here:
http://www.filedropper.com/hserrpid32252

Comment: Launch Eclipse in console, do the same use case and tell us, what the exception in the bash console shows.
By the way: Why the hell do you manually write imports in Eclipse? Either you begin to type the class (you don't need to completely write it), let's say GoogleM (to import GoogleMap) and press STRG + SPACE. After you made your choice, the import is added autmatically. Or you type STRG + SHIFT + O to reorganize all imports with one command.

Comment: I did and I put result to my q

Comment: Is there any special information in /home/nemesis/NEW_Android_Development_Enviroment/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/hs_err_pid9886.log?

Do you have the same problems with a fresh workspace? Maybe it is related to any plugin you use.

Comment: I don't know it there is some special information. I am beginner here. That's why I uploaded that file. I have installed eclipse also on another disc and it crashes the same way. I tried it in a new workspace  but it crashes there too. :/ I read on other thread "This is a bug inside JRE. You can do nothing about this, just send a bug report to the link pointed. Try to use 32-bit version instead of 64. Try to use another JRE version (not 6.0_27-b07)."

Comment: I am importing some libs manually because i am following one yt tutorial...

Comment: Try to run with the latest SDK (Java 8) and see if the error is gone: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && 
sudo apt-get update && 
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: I uninstalled java 1.7.0_45 and I Install java 1.8.0_20 but it didnt help :/

Comment: I just found out that it happend not only when i want to import librarly but It crashes everytime when that pop up help window shows... like when i want to call something item. and then it gives me options to choose and it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 6 hours I have found solution....

To solve this issue, try to put this line (slightly different from -Dorg...)

org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
at the end of this file

eclipse/configuration/config.ini

I am so happy and angry at the same time.

Thanks for help to everyone :)